# Inheritance - __hash__ sets to None in a subclass

Tags: python, inheritance

I managed to reproduce this on both Python 3.4 and 3.7.

Consider:

```
class Comparable:
    def _key(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self._key())

    def __eq__(self, other):
        ...

    def __lt__(self, other):
        ...


class A(Comparable): pass

class B(A):
    def __str__(self):
        return "d"

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(self, type(other))

    def _key(self):
        return str(self),

b = B()
```

Clearly one would expect `b.__hash__` to be defined here, since it is defined under `Comparable` which `B` is a subclass of.

Lo and behold, it is defined, but evaluates to `None`. What gives?

```
>> b
<__main__.B object at 0x00000183C9734978>
>> '__hash__' in dir(b)
True
>> b.__hash__

>> b.__hash__ is None
True
>> B.__mro__
(<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.Comparable'>, <class 'object'>)
>> isinstance(b, Comparable)
True
```

The same behavior is reproduced if implementing `__init__` as `super().__init__()` in `Comparable` and `A`.

Comment: It is already not available in `A`

Comment: In 2.7 : `b.__hash__ is None` => True

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Found it in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__):

> A class that overrides `__eq__()` and does not define `__hash__()` will have its `__hash__()` implicitly set to None.

and

> If a class that overrides `__eq__()` needs to retain the implementation of `__hash__()` from a parent class, the interpreter must be told this explicitly by setting `__hash__ = <ParentClass>.__hash__`

From ticket [1549](https://bugs.python.org/issue1549):

> This was done intentionally -- if you define a comparison without
>   defining a hash, the default hash will not match your comparison, and
>   your objects will misbehave when used as dictionary keys.

(Guido van Rossum)

Comment: Ah, should have checked the docs myself. Guess I was too busy smashing my head on the wall.

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the game here but I had the same problem. In my case, I also have 197 classes that derive from an abstract base class. I didn't want to copy-paste a ton of instances of...

```
def __hash__(self) -> int:
    return hash('HASH LOGIC GOES HERE')
```

...so I did the following, which works for me:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__class__.__hash__ = Base.__hash__  # <----- SOLUTION


    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        return hash('HASH LOGIC GOES HERE')


class Derived(Base):
    def __eq__(self, other) -> bool:
        return isinstance(other, Derived)  # or whatever logic


if __name__ == '__main__':
    derived = Derived()
    print(f'derived.__hash__: {derived.__hash__}')
    print(f'hash(derived):    {hash(derived)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can nowadays inject `__hash__` (and `__eq__`, ...) into derived classes by modifying the **class** of the derived class type, once the derived class has been created, like so:

```py
class Base:
    def __hash__(self) -> int: return ...
    def __post_init__(cls):
        cls.__hash__ = Base.__hash__

class Derived(Base):
    ...

d = Derived()
hash(d) # this will call Base.__hash__(d)
```

This was [added in python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation)