# Django model objects became not hashable after upgrading to django 2.2

Tags: python, django, django-2.2

I'm testing the update of an application from Django 2.1.7 to 2.2.12. I got an error when running my unit tests, which boils down to a model object not being hashable :

```
    Station.objects.all().delete()
py37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py:710: in delete
    collector.collect(del_query)
py37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\deletion.py:192: in collect
    reverse_dependency=reverse_dependency)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <django.db.models.deletion.Collector object at 0x000001EC78243E80>
objs = <QuerySet [<Station(nom='DUNKERQUE')>, <Station(nom='STATION1')>, <Station(nom='STATION2')>]>, source = None, nullable = False
reverse_dependency = False

    def add(self, objs, source=None, nullable=False, reverse_dependency=False):
        """
        Add 'objs' to the collection of objects to be deleted.  If the call is
        the result of a cascade, 'source' should be the model that caused it,
        and 'nullable' should be set to True if the relation can be null.

        Return a list of all objects that were not already collected.
        """
        if not objs:
            return []
        new_objs = []
        model = objs[0].__class__
        instances = self.data.setdefault(model, set())
        for obj in objs:
>           if obj not in instances:
E           TypeError: unhashable type: 'Station'
```

Instances of model objects [are hashable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378318/are-django-model-instances-hashable) in Django, once they are saved to database and get a primary key.

I don't understand where the error comes from and why I get this when running this basic code:

```
In [7]: s = Station.objects.create(nom='SOME PLACE')

In [8]: hash(s)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-9333020f3184> in <module>
----> 1 hash(s)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'Station'

In [9]: s.pk
Out[9]: 2035
```

All this code works fine when I switch back to Django 2.1.7. The same happens with other model objects in the app. I'm using python version 3.7.2 on Windows, with a SQlite backend (on the development workstation).

Edit: Here's the definition of the model referred to above:

```
class Station(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nom

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Station(nom='{}')>".format(self.nom)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Station) and self.nom == other.nom
```

Comment: Have you seen [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30333)? Are you overriding `__eq__` in your `Station` model?

Comment: Hi @Alasdair, I hadn't but that's exactly it, my models override `__eq__`. Overriding `__hash__` fixes the problem. Do you want to write an answer so I can give you credit ?

Comment: Glad that helped. Happy for you to add your own answer you probably know the details better than me.

Comment: Actually, if this helped in identifying the reason (since django 2.2, an instance of a model overriding `__eq__` but not `__hash__` has a hash set to None), the fix suggested in the ticket doesn't seem appropriate to me : every instance would return the same hash (unless I'm missing something), which is of course not the correct behaviour.

Comment: If you set `__hash__ = models.Model.__hash__` in Django 2.2, then `Student(pk=1)` and `Student(pk=2)` will have different hashes. `Student(pk=1)` and `OtherModel(pk=1)` will have the same hash, because the [`Model.__hash__`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2/django/db/models/base.py#L534) method returns `hash(self.pk)`. That's the same behaviour in Django 2.1. If you want different models with the same pk to return different hashes then you need to override `__hash__` in Django 2.1 and 2.2.

Comment: I was trying to be smart with my fix, by overriding `__hash__` rather than reassigning it, but got it wrong. All clear, thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As pointed out by @Alasdair, the issue was a change of behaviour brought in Django 2.2 to comply with how a model class should behave when `__eq__()` is overriden but not `__hash__()`. As per the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) for `__hash__()`:

> A class that overrides `__eq__()` and does not define `__hash__()` will
>   have its `__hash__()` implicitly set to None.

More information about the implementation of this behaviour in Django can be found in [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30333).

The fix can be either the one suggested in the ticket, i.e. re-assigning the `__hash__()` method of the model to the one of the super class:
`__hash__ = models.Model.__hash__`

Or a more object-oriented way could be:

```
    def __hash__(self):
        return super().__hash__()
```

This seems a bit weird because this should be unnecessary: by default, a call to `__hash__()` should use the method from the super class where it's implemented. This suggests Django breaks encapsulation somehow. But maybe I don't understand everything. Anyway that's a sidenote.

In my case, I still wanted to be able to compare model instances not yet saved to the database for testing purposes and ended up with this implementation :

```
    def __hash__(self):
        if self.pk is None:
            return hash(self.nom)
        return super().__hash__()
```

Comment: I wouldn't describe it as *Django* breaking encapsulation. In 2.2+ it's following the documented Python behaviour. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53519136/) links to [ticket 1549](https://bugs.python.org/issue1549), where Guido explains it's so that  *your objects don't misbehave when used as dictionary keys*.